How to find toolchain in xcode 15.0.1
Failed to build module 'PayUCheckoutProKit'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.9 (swiftlang-5.9.0.128.108 clang-1500.0.40.1)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.
How to update Toolchain in xcode 15.0.1 I didn’t find toolchain things

Is PayUCheckoutProKit integrated with Carthage? It looks like your framework was built with Xcode 14 and then cached. Now you have updated your Xcode, and the cache has the old version.

How do I remove all caches that block the run of my project?

Clean the content of these folders: 1. ~/Library/Caches/carthage 2. ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit 3. ./Carthage in the folder of your project
